# Highstock with MySQL data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have php file which produce data in JSON format values.php , file where I want to display chart index.html and JS data1.js.

Code in values.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$data = array();
$count = 0;
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sensor ORDER BY id ASC ") or die ("Connection error");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//echo "[" . $row['time'] . "," . $row['value']. "]"."," ;
  $newdate = strtotime($row['time']) * 1000; 
$data[] = array($newdate, (float)$row['value']);
$count++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

In index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DS18B20</title>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10" />
<script src="/jstest1/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="/jstest1/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="/jstest1/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And JS data1.js

```
$(function() {
        $.getJSON('/jstest1/values.php', function (data) {
// Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Temperature'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'Temperature',
            data : data,
            marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 3
            },
            shadow : true,
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
});
```

Seems all OK, but I don't know why not displaying graph in browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntuzz.png)
Output of data : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiWlC.png)

Maybe someone will see some mistake. Maybe mistake in syntax JSON data rows ?

Comment: It seems like you are not using your `data1.js` in index.html so the function never gets called?

Comment: How your JSON looks like? Could you paste it here?

Comment: [[1461227903000,25.75],[1461227910000,25.75],[1461230530000,25.87]]

Comment: YES! Thank you very much, Sebastian ! I added this in html and all works great!
<script type="text/javascript" src="data1.js" ></script>